# Can the same entity refile an abandoned patent application?

Tags: abadoned, refile

A university's technology commercialization office filed a patent in 2007 and it's status today is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action".

Could this same University file this patent again?  From what I hear, the University representative was fired so this slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original pre-grant publication of the patent application from 2007 would be used to reject any new filing for the same subject matter. This could only be avoided if the applicant was allowed to revive the abandoned patent application (extremely unlikely as the applicant would be required to demonstrate that correcting the failure to respond was unavoidable or unintentional for the entire period).